# Server Side Event with servlets for multiple connected clients

Tags: java, html, servlets, jakarta-ee, server-sent-events

I am new to server push technologies .I have done some research and come know about the Server Sent Event.

I am implementing a live monitoring software. My back end is built with java servlets. There will be around 30 to 50 browser will remain connected  to the server at the same time.

With my research I have 3 questions in my mind.

1. Do I have to use an infinite loop so that client should not pole again after 5 seconds, which it will do if I do not use an infinite loop?
2. As we all  know server creates a separate thread for each incoming request and run service method of servlet so If I am using an infinite loop in my servlet to run the process as described in my first point above and there are 50 connected clients at a time. So does it mean there will be separate 50 threads that will be keep running? Lets say the number of clients will increase from 50 to 100, will the threads increase from  50 to 100 and so on?
3. If I am right in point 2 above then sse is not good for live monitoring in my case. Will it drain my server resources as the number of clients will increase ?

Answer (score 0):

Answers

1. Yes, If you are using servlets you have to have an infinite loop, probably with a sleep in.
2. Also correct, you will use one thread per request, and these threads will be the http listener thread from you servlet container.
3. Yes, when there are no more http listener threads, request will be rejected. You can easily have 200 threads on a Tomcat, and if all you do is sleep and send back a little data to each client it will probably work.

However, **this this does not sound like a problem I would solve using the servlet API**, especially if there is a chance you ever need to scale beyond  200 client. Instead I would use an end-to-end NIO solution, which means you di  not require a thread per connection.

You probably want to take a look at Netty, or [RatPack](https://ratpack.io/), they have a different programming style than the servlet API, but it sounds like a better choice. It is event driven, and you can have thousands of connected client and you would still only use 1 thread per CPU core.

If you choose to use a servlet container, I would recommend that you get familiar with the Spring framework. It is actually possible to create a solution with Spring where you don't use the http listener thread, but offloads to a different thread pool.

Another possible solution (since your clients are browsers) is to use WebSockets, here I would also use the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to do that, as long as you keep somewhere the connection to the client, you can send data at a given event (like a connection request, a timer event, etc...)
2. This is not true. SSE is combined with asynchronous servlets, that share a single connection for multiple clients.
3. AFAIK (but not benchmarked), SSE is lighter than any other similar alternative, including websockets.

If you want to see an example of lightweight SSE in servlets by using the JEaSSE library, please have a look to the README: https://github.com/mariomac/jeasse